# react-native integrating with existing ios apps

Tags: ios, react-native

Have followed the instructions from here:

```
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/embedded-app-ios.html#content
```

I am able to install required react sub specs and react spec with `pod install`
I was able to run the local react server to serve the bundles as well.

But I am seeing the following issues which is preventing my app from starting up in the iOS simulator.

```
/.../node_modules/react-native/React/Executors/RCTContextExecutor.m:560:7: Comparison of function 'JSGlobalContextSetName' not equal to a null pointer is always true


/.../node_modules/react-native/React/Base/RCTRootView.m:230:17: Method override for the designated initializer of the superclass '-initWithFrame:' not found
```

Can anybody help decyphering whats going on? Seems like it is specific to the RCTRootView implementation inside react library.

Answer (score 1):

i figured the problem was with where i started the react-native app. It was not running from the project root. fixing that fixed the starting of the app in the simulator and these warnings werent the real root cause.